# React Native Beginning

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

When I try to lunch my simple application on Android Emulator the result is red box looks like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr8Tt.png)

in addition to this tip:
" When you see Red Box with stack trace, you can click any
  stack frame to jump to the source file. The packager will launch your
  editor of choice. It will first look at REACT_EDITOR environment
  variable, then at EDITOR. To set it up, you can add something like
  export REACT_EDITOR=atom to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc depending on
  which shell you use." 
I am still junior in this field and have my first steps. May someone tell me how to deal with this problem in detail.

Comment: Can we see your code? Can you make a repo?

Comment: 'import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import header from './SRC/Components/header';
import albumlist from './SRC/Components/albumlist';

//create a component
const App = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <header headerText={'Albums!'} />
    <albumlist />
  </View>
  );

//Render it to a device
//AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
AppRegistry.register.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
//style={{ flex: 1 }} this command is used to scroll the screen down and up as I
//want not to return up again
'

Comment: this code is the code written in the index.js it is based on a course I have talking about this topic

Comment: It is hard to parse your code without formatting. But I'm curious about `AppRegistry.register.registerComponent`. Shouldn't it just be `AppRegistry.registerComponent`?

Comment: Hmmm.. I think that according to my search before asking here but when I remove "register" more error messages appear.

Comment: What error do you get then?